# Calling Kotlin from Java, android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have kotlin class as below

```
class FullPlayerEdpisodeViewKt(context: Context, appCMSPresenter: AppCMSPresenter) : RelativeLayout(context) {
private var lpView: LayoutParams? = null

init {
    lpView = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    layoutParams = lpView
    setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)

    if (appCMSPresenter.getTrailerPlayerView().parent != null) {
        appCMSPresenter.episodePlayerViewParent = appCMSPresenter.getTrailerPlayerView().parent as ViewGroup
        (appCMSPresenter.getTrailerPlayerView().parent as ViewGroup).removeView(appCMSPresenter.getTrailerPlayerView())
    }
    appCMSPresenter.getTrailerPlayerView().layoutParams = lpView
    appCMSPresenter.getTrailerPlayerView().updateFullscreenButtonState(Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    appCMSPresenter.getTrailerPlayerView().getPlayerView().controller.hide()
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
    appCMSPresenter.getTrailerPlayerView().isClickable = true
    addView(appCMSPresenter.getTrailerPlayerView())
}
}
```

It resides in package

```
package views.customviews;
```

In another java class I am calling it as

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayoutFull = new FullPlayerEdpisodeViewKt(currentActivity, this);
```

I am getting error

```
cannot find symbol
        relativeLayoutFull = new views.customviews.FullPlayerEdpisodeViewKt(currentActivity, this);
                                                               ^
symbol:   class FullPlayerEdpisodeViewKt
 location: package views.customviews
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: 1. are you implemented AppCMSPresenter

Comment: please make check of the relative paths, and instead of writing manually `views.customviews.FullPlayerEdpisodeViewKt` just write `FullPlayerEdpisodeViewKt` an let android studio find for you, it wont show error then

Comment: @Achy97 tried that but still doesn't work

Comment: is android studio successfully showing suggestion for the intended class?

Comment: @Achy97 It shows suggestion for import, still while building get the same error

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot find a symbol" is compilation error. you should see compile time error there. See the hint Android studio is giving on that line